# Why is as.POSIXct adding 1 hour to my time?

Tags: r, time

Below is my R-code that is behaving weirdly. I expect a time of 22:00 as entered but i get 23:00.

```
as.POSIXct(chron(dates="01/04/06",times="22:00:00"),tz="CET")
[1] "2006-01-04 23:00:00 CET"
```

In the next line of my code i use the results to select a window from an xts/zoo object: Therefore just ignoring the error and instead entering 21:00 (in above) wasnt useful since it returns the wrong data. Windowing with the result of the code above returns the correct values.

```
head(qs<-as.zoo(window(Q,start=as.POSIXct(chron(dates="01/04/06",times="22:00:00"),tz="CET"),end=as.POSIXct(chron(dates="01/05/06",times="21:00:00"),tz="CET"))))
```

Here is a sample set of the data (`Q`):

```
Stage.Qm  Flow.Qm Stage.QmDB Flow.QmDB Stage.Q1000 Flow.Q1000 Stage.Q1000DB Flow.Q1000DB
2006-01-04 23:00:00 541.1589 5.636957   541.1592  5.646017    541.5708   20.44692      541.5708     20.44692
2006-01-04 23:01:00 541.1589 5.637268   541.1592  5.645087    541.5701   20.41321      541.5701     20.41321
2006-01-04 23:02:00 541.1589 5.638604   541.1588  5.635806    541.5701   20.40946      541.5701     20.40946
2006-01-04 23:03:00 541.1589 5.638979   541.1588  5.635694    541.5704   20.42712      541.5704     20.42712
2006-01-04 23:04:00 541.1589 5.639619   541.1590  5.640691    541.5710   20.45848      541.5710     20.45848
2006-01-04 23:05:00 541.1590 5.640662   541.1591  5.641682    541.5715   20.47893      541.5715     20.4789
```

Comment: In the documentation you can read: "The current implementation of chron objects does not handle time zones nor daylight savings time." Thus, a solution would be to not use `chron` here.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed to  `as.POSIXct(strptime("2006-01-04 22:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))` and this gives the desired 
`[1] "2006-01-04 22:00:00 CET"`

Comment: 1. You don't need `strptime` there. 2. I recommend always setting the time zone explicitly. 3. Feel free to write an answer to your question.

Comment: Can you please use my code (in the comment above) and give an example. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the documentation you can read: "The current implementation of chron objects does not handle time zones nor daylight savings time." Thus, a solution would be to not use `chron` here.

Just use `as.POSIXct.default`:

```
as.POSIXct("2006-01-04 22:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="CET")
[1] "2006-01-04 22:00:00 CET"
```

Comment: i have a somewhat related question that is not answerd by the above. can you tell me what is happening here? `> q1
2015-12-31 22:00:00 
           40.99648 
> q2
2015-12-31 22:00:00 
           40.99648 
> cbind(q1,q2)
                          q1       q2
2015-12-31 23:00:00 40.99648 40.99648
`  the time changes when i do cbind or when i do nay operation on q1 and q2 by 1 hour including saving into a list.

Comment: @jjunju If you have a new question, please ask a new question. Don't forget to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059) when you do that.